# change emacs encoding of a bunch of files all at once (UTF-8)

Tags: encoding, emacs

I was wondering if there is a way of changing the encoding in emacs permanently and if there is a way to change the encoding of a bunch of files already written all at once. (to UTF-8) (All those files are in the same directory, and I would want to change the encoding all at once rather than file by file...)

I know it's possible to use: "revert-buffer-with-coding-system" to change the encoding of a file.

Thank you very much for your response,
Antonio